# Button-variant mixin not found bootstrap

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4

I was trying to change the color of bootstrap-info button for bootstrap 4. Doing this:

```
      $mynewcolor:#77cccc;

      .btn-info {
          @include button-variant($mynewcolor, darken($mynewcolor, 7.5%), darken($mynewcolor, 10%), lighten($mynewcolor,5%), lighten($mynewcolor, 10%), darken($mynewcolor,30%));
      }

      .btn-info {
          @include button-outline-variant($mynewcolor, #222222, lighten($mynewcolor,5%), $mynewcolor);
      }
```

However, my scss compiler throws :

> "message": "no mixin named button-variant"

I tried adding:

```
 @import "bootstrap/mixins";
```

on top of the line but I get:

> "message": "File to import not found or unreadable:

Comment: Probably wrong path

Comment: Did you find a solution? having the same problem

Comment: It has been so long I don't even remember if I found it or not :) Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us more details on how you load your bootstrap and where the source files are.

As far as I can tell, the `mixins` should be under `/scss/` folder. So you might try to change the path to:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```